# Can a grounded static-shielding antistatic bag be used as a circuitry work surface to protect from ESD?

Tags: esd, shielding, antistatic, static, workbench

Basically, I have looked around about how to take proper care with respect to ESD and I am quite confused. I know an antistatic bag of any type would not provide additional protection from ESD if used as a work surface but, if I understand the principles correctly, then wrapping a **static-shielding** antistatic bag to an antistatic wrist bracelet and connecting it to proper ground would **do** provide additional ESD protection for placing ESD sensitive devices and anything on it and working with them (while also having properly grounded oneself of course), because technically, the bag would shield from the underlying surface in terms of static, and it would also be grounded, so as to provide a safe dissipation route for static.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, I would appreciate it if someone could explain what makes it wrong from a theoretical perspective.

**EDIT**: It's probably not going to be ok for some serious work on PCBs, I am mostly asking from a theoretical perspective. Also another reason I am asking is because all I want to do is take [this](https://udooorgcdn-aidilabsrl.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/x86_top_h.png) Single-Board Computer, put a 30mm fan on the heatsink, add [this m.2 ssd drive](https://i1.rozetka.ua/goods/214150/transcend_ts128gmts600_images_214150177.jpg) and put it in either [this acrylic case](https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/005/706/979/93fe891b857c37dceb39848e47fef4e4_original.png?w=680&fit=max&v=1460541262&auto=format&lossless=true&s=59b4c6c8f2e5278e9d429ef07a63b1f5), or [this metal case](https://shop.udoo.org/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/460x345/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/u/d/udoox86_metalcase1.jpg). What are the minimum precautions I have to take? Can I simply ground the static-shielding bag somehow and drop everything on it (screws, spacers, ssd and SBC) and assemble the thing? Otherwise, will it be ok if I only do it without letting anything touch any surface other than my (grounded) hands (I know it takes a bit of juggling)?

Comment: In theory its a good idea. In practice you will find the surface getting scratched and punctured from PCB leads, solder splash, etc, so count on replacing it often.

Comment: Which side? No it's not an approved method.  But bare wood is good.  ( like hardwood unfinished flooring , butcher block maple)

Comment: An old aluminum cookie sheet tied to ground through a 10M resistor will work for tasks where the device is not energized.

Comment: @AlmostDone this sounds just about in line with what I have understood so far. Yes, the device is not going to be on or even connected to a plug.